# MySql Query - Need 'ORDER BY' option for conditions based

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table, structure is given below:-

```
Where i_status means
i_status 0 = Active
i_status 1 = Archived
i_status 2 = Deleted

and fk_replaced_by_id contains the active records id that will be considered parent record.

Table structure is

id--completion_date--i_status--fk_replaced_by_id
1 --15-Dec-2013    --0       --0
2 --15-Dec-2013    --0       --0
3 --14-Dec-2013    --2       --0
4 --07-Dec-2013    --1       --1
5 --08-Dec-2013    --1       --1
6 --13-Dec-2013    --0       --0
```

I want to show listing in a order, `Order by completion_date, and archived records should be under the parent, and in deleted should be in last` :-

```
id--completion_date--i_status--fk_replaced_by_id
1 --15-Dec-2013    --0       --0
4 --07-Dec-2013    --1       --1
5 --08-Dec-2013    --1       --1
2 --15-Dec-2013    --0       --0
6 --13-Dec-2013    --0       --0
3 --14-Dec-2013    --2       --0
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT *
FROM assessments
ORDER BY i_completion_date DESC, i_status ASC
```

But this query return only order by `completion_date` sequence, But I always need active on top having greatest `completetion_date`, and archived of that record should be under to parent record.

Any idea please ?

Comment: 'fk_replaced_by_id' contains the parent record id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to force all "DELETED" records at the end (and this is not supporting deleted with parent reference), do a case/when... or with MySQL an IF()  in this case

if( i_status = 2, 2, 1 )

Stating if the i_status = 2 (deleted), I want all of them sorted in SECOND GROUP, everything else goes in FIRST GROUP.

Now, to handle parent.  You will need to get the parent's completion date too if there is one via a self-join

```
select
      YT.ID,
      YT.Completion_Date,
      YT.I_Status,
      YT.FK_Replaced_By_ID,
      YT2.Completion_Date as ParentCompleted
   from
      YourTable YT
         LEFT JOIN YourTable YT2
            ON YT.FK_Replaced_By_ID = YT2.ID
   order by
      IF( YT.I_Status = 2, 2, 1 ),
      IF( YT2.ID IS NULL, YT.Completion_Date, YT2.Completion_Date ) DESC,
      IF( YT2.ID IS NULL, YT.ID, YT2.ID ),
      YT.Completion_Date DESC
```

Now to clarify the rest of the ORDER BY.

First, IF() is for the status as described.  We want all  DELETED pushed to the bottom via 2, and anything else considered in group 1.

Next IF().  If there IS a parent ID (via matching ID in second instance of same table via self-join), then grab the date of the PARENT'S record (alias YT2).  If no parent, then it IS its own record and use its own completion date (alias YT).  This way, any child records that had older dates will be pull up to the same date grouping as its parent, not broken down to their older date.

Now, what if there are many transactions on the same date, especially since there is no timestamp reference.  Here too I am saying that within the same date (previous IF() above), put the record grouped by either the parent ID, or the ID itself.  In a similar fashion to the completion date, the parent and child records will all be bunched together. So this IF() is using the ID or Parent ID to keep together.

Finally since all the respective SUBGROUPS have been established, now sort THOSE by actual completion date of their original (non-parent) record.

I guess what I missed on the 4/5 records being out of order, this should wrap that up for you...  Instead of the last order by "YT.Completion_Date DESC", change to

```
   IF( YT2.ID IS NULL, 1, 2),
   YT.Completion_Date
```

This will force the Parent ID first, THEN do the others in natural date order.

Comment: Deleted records are listing perfectly!!, but 'ID' 4 and 5 should be under '1' is not getting properly

Comment: @Suleman, sorry I was away... but marked as ok... did something just work, or did you figure the final adjustment out.  I see it and adjusted order by clause.. see comment at end to supercede only the LAST completion date order by component.

Comment: Not a issue - yeah now working perfectly when just one check is added for fk_replaced_by_id.

Comment: I have added one more record in db that having date '16-dec-2013', our one scenario is missed, now it should be on top ?

Comment: Can we have a chat discussion ?

Comment: @Suleman, I'm available but time-zone difference may hinder it... You start and provide a link and I'll check in periodically to help.

Comment: Thank you for kind attention. Now I have split this into two queries because of there were some rules - only consider completion date order if it is greater than next 'current' and always show archived in between irrespective of completion date and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order by parent, than statuses and date in the last, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM assessments
ORDER BY i_status ASC, fk_replaced_by_id ASC, i_completion_date DESC
```

I don't know what is your parent column, you don't tell us.

Comment: 1st priority is active records, then archived will be listed under the active then deleted.

Comment: Try my select, is there what you need? It sorts by i_status in your order, than py fk_replaced_by_id (your parent?) inside i_status groups and than by date.

Comment: While still learning, your order by will put all of like status together in individual groups leaving active and archived separated.  What if DELETED Status was ID = 1, and active was 5 and there were others.  Also nothing to keep parent/child records together.

Comment: I have no information about correct answer, author want to get from us. I don't understand, why ID's 1,2,6 in topic are in a different places and try to help with information that I read this.

Comment: @BaBL86, take a look at my answer, and if it STILL doesn't make sense, think of each order by as it's own group of things (but not an actual GROUP BY which implies aggregations such as min, max, count, avg, etc).  Then within each common group of things, split those piles into the next level of piles.. hence the items that HAVE a parent are in the same pile as the parent itself, and in the same order based on the PARENT's date basis.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fk_replaced_by_id` of any parent is `0`:

```
SELECT *
FROM assessments
ORDER BY if( fk_replaced_by_id = 0, id, fk_replaced_by_id ), i_status
```